# Can you have subprocesss.Popen retain color in stdout/stderr?

Tags: python, python-2.7, popen

I have the following code:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '), env=os.environ, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    while(True):
      log.info(p.stdout.readline())
      if(p.poll() is not None):
        break
```

Which works ok, except for the fact that it removes all color issued. Is there a way to retain this?

Comment: Which commands are you running? Note that programs like, say, `grep` check which type of output file they are using and will not output color codes if it doesn't look like a terminal. If you want to force it to always send the color codes you have to use the option `--color=always`.  Other programs do the same

Comment: Ah sure, makes sense - the command I'm trying in this example is `ansible` based commands. Ran outside of the script, beautiful rainbows of colors. In the script, not as pretty.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56835373/94148

Comment: colored output can be tricky... some programs (such as `git`) disable colors by default when they're part of  `Popen('foo')`.  If I'm having problems with colored output, almost invariably, the fault lies with the thing I'm calling from `Popen()`.  Try forcing colors with CLI options (if `foo` it has them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not specify whan `cmd` is, but some programs do not emit the [escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) necessary for color output on a terminal when they determine that their standard output is not actually connected to a terminal.

Depending on the program you may or may not be able to override that.

With `ansible`, you can set the [`force_color`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#force-color) configuration variable to 1 to force color output.

Comment: Beautiful! While you're here, any idea how I can get my output to stop printing extra `\n` on every line? (I can't accept your answer for another few minutes, sorry!)

Answer (score -1):

Add the following at the top of your Python script.

```
import os
os.environ['ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR'] = "TRUE"
```

Now if you run Ansible from Python by using `subprocess.Popen`, it will print the colors.